# how i can use the specified compiler gcc-mp-4.7 in xcode?

Tags: c++, macos

All,
I used the macports to install the gcc-mp-4.7 and the boost library. How i can use them in my c++ project in xcode IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You should just keep using the MacPorts one.  You just need to point your compiler at the right library path to link against, which is where libboost_regex is, probably /opt/local/lib or similar.

Comment: Thanks, i found the binary library builded by the macports. The path is /opt/local/lib/. Thanks for your information.